# Substituting one method behavior in C# Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

Good morning

I need to substitute a behavior of only one method of a real instanced class (not a mocked class) in C# Unit Test.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually you will create an override method with a different parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a subclass and override this method.

```
public class BaseClass 
{ 
  
    public virtual void SomeMethod() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Hi"); 
    } 
} 
  
// Derived Class 
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass 
{ 
  
    public override void SomeMethod()  
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Hello"); 
    } 
}
```

If the method if interrest is not marked as virtual and you can't change the code, you still can hide it(which I personally would never do):

```
public class BaseClass 
{ 
  
    public void SomeMethod() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Hi"); 
    } 
} 
  
// Derived Class 
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass 
{ 
  
    public new void SomeMethod()  
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Hello"); 
    } 
}
```